# Loading a list of images in one-by-one sequence

Tags: flutter

After getting a list of image urls from firebase using StreamBuilder

i used a ListView.builder with a TransitionToImage from this package:

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_advanced_networkimage

and made a list of images.

here is my Streambuilder / builder code :

```
builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('loading...');
        var doc = snapshot.data;
        List<String> pages = List.from(doc['pages']);
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: pages.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return TransitionToImage(
                AdvancedNetworkImage("a url", timeoutDuration: Duration(minutes: 1)),
                placeholder: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              );
            });
      },
```

the ListView.builder loads all the images in random order at once, which doesn't look that natural for me or the users.

is there a way to make ListView.builder load a image, after the image in the previous index has been loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [precacheImage](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html) to load the images in `pages` one-by-one and when arrived replace the URL in `pages` so that the real image is shown instead of a placeholder.

```
for(final page in pages) {
  await precacheImage(page.downloadUrl, context);
  page.displayUrl = page.downloadUrl;
  setState(() => pages = pages.toList();
}
```